# PDF IText-7 layout support for Persian language?

Tags: itext, itext7

I have tried lots of ways to use PDF Itext-7 with the Persian language, but none of the ways was success.
The way I have tried:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("fonts/NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true/false);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.setFont(font);
//paragraph.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
paragraph.add("فارسی");//.setFontScript(Character.UnicodeScript.ARABIC);
```

AND

```
final FontSet set = new FontSet();
set.addFont("fonts/NotoSansArabic-Regular.ttf");
set.addFont("fonts/FreeSans.ttf");
document.setFontProvider(new FontProvider(set));
...
```

And many more ways, but none of them solved the problem.

I am wondering such a framework even not support none English language?

OR is there anything left I did not set up?

I have used some examples from [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/displaying-text-different-languages-single-pdf-document), but also not working.

What is the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using pdfCalligraph, like the examples you listed mention?

Comment: PdfCalligraph is not open-source and needs a commercial license. But I want to use my own font which does not work, I have tried some other example without using pdfCalligraph, also not working.

Comment: you'll need pdfCalligraph.

Comment: @AndréLemos What about this example which does not use pdfCalligraph: https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part3/chapter11/Listing_11_18_Ligatures2.java

Comment: check line 45&46 on the link you've shared